# Know push id of android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a android device (phone) which is registered with GCM servers and have valid push id which custom applications can use to send notifications using GCM.

Is there any way to find this registered push id of this device (using this device only)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GetGCMdeviceId.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class GetGCMdeviceId {

    String GcmProjectID = "YOUR_GCM_PROJCTID";
    Context _con;

    public GetGCMdeviceId(Context c) {
        _con = c;
    }

    public String deviceid() {

        checkNotNull(GcmProjectID, "SENDER_ID");
        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(_con);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(_con);
        String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(_con);

        Log.d("Registration Info", "registration id: " + regId);
        System.out.println("Registration Id 1--->:" + regId);

        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(_con, GcmProjectID);
            System.out.println("Registration Id 2--->:" + regId);

        } else {
            Log.v("Registration Info", "Already registered");
        }
        return regId;

    }

    private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
        if (reference == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
    }
}
```

use above code to get your device GCMID
just create above class in your package

then create object of above class and pass the context to it from the class in which your calling it

```
GetGCMdeviceId gcm=new GetGCMdeviceId (this);
String gcmId=gcm.deviceid();
```

Comment: thanks android. So it seems that there is no other ready-made way available "in the OS" to get id without having to write and execute Android API JAVA code

Comment: Actually GCM provides its library code to get GCMID and GCMID is given by GoogleCloudServer which is generated from combination of your project id and your sender id

Comment: Apologies if I am asking very basic question. But is push id of device is depended on project id in google? I thought it's unique, one-per-device, and same is used for all the applications/projects worldwide!

Comment: no its not same for all application its same for only that application which project id and sender id is assoicated with your request

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/  use this link to understand flow of GCM ID generation

Answer (score 0):

use `getRegistrationId` to get the device id.

```
   String regID = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

For more info see [Android GCM getRegistrationId](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#getRegistrationId(android.content.Context))

Answer (score 0):

Use [getRegistrationId()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#getRegistrationId(android.content.Context)):

```
// Get GCM registration id
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

> Gets the current registration id for application on GCM service.
>
> If result is empty, the registration has failed.